# How to print the field_collection_item in node.tpl.php?

Tags: drupal

In my content type I have fields to display the extra related links, along with the title and body part how can I print the related links in the node page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print `$node->body` for displaying all the custom fields with body and title.

All you need to do is give some CSS for this.